# Log file growth due to replication issue

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication

I have one primary database and it's getting replicated to another server. Both servers are SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP1. Replication was running fine till last week. We have transaction log backup every five minutes. I don't see any issue with log backup. Transactional Replication is setup as pull replication on secondary server. Distributor runs on secondary server. Everything was running fine till last week. This database is not mirrored. But cdc is enabled on the database. IsSyncWithBackup status is 0.

All of a sudden from last week, I see following message in last action column of Log Reader Agent even though replication monitor shows replication is in sync with no latency (??)

> Replicated transactions are waiting for next Log backup or for mirroring partner to catch up.

@Kin, Sorry. This is the first time I am using stackexchange portal. For some reason, I am not able to add comments to your replies. So, I am editing original post based on replies I am getting.

@Mike, It showed REPLICATION for log_reuse_wait_desc for the database set up in replication.

As a last resort, we dropped the replication and we will recreate it after business hours today. As of now, this issue is resolved. Still not sure though what caused it in first place. Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: Any chance you have mirroring enabled ? Also look at [TF 1448](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx). Also from the error, it is clear that you are using mirroring and your principal and mirror are not in sync.

Comment: Also, for replication if `sync with backup` is true then you have to disable it on Publication database `EXEC sp_replicationdboption 'PublisherDB','sync with backup',false`. Refer to [Enable Coordinated Backups for Transactional Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147311.aspx)

Comment: Can you run this query and share the results for log_reuse_wait_description for the particular database - `select * from sys.databases`